# Access MongoDB directly via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, mongodb, database

is there any possibility to access and retrieve data from MongoDB directly over JavaScript form browser without backend processing?

Comment: Another option would be to evaluate [CouchDb](http://couchdb.apache.org/). Here you have a full REST interface included

Answer (score 17):

MongoDB natively does not have a fully usable REST interface. You will need either Python based Sleepy Mongoose or Node.js based MongoDB Rest

Please see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface for more information.

Mongo's inbuilt REST interface is very basic & read only.

Comment: I was able to benchmark both Python based Sleepy Mongoose and Node.js based mongodb-rest. Node.js was an absolute winner with more then 600 req/sec throughput of my hello-world test.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to host your database on MongoLabs, they also expose a REST API. Watch out, it's not secure, as an API key is passed with each request, but your could use it to retrieve public data through Javascript:

https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-Is-there-a-REST-API-for-MongoDB-

Once you have your mongolab db setup, you can access it thru REST request such as

```
$.getJSON("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/your-db/collections/your-collection/?apiKey=your-key", function(json) {
  //console.log( "JSON Data: " + json );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in the standard security context.

If you have a situation where you have elevated security rights (such as inside a custom browser extension) then it may become possible.

Comment: Yes, although I doubt one exists already, so you would have to write it.

Comment: You should explain How??