# JavaScript driver for mongo that has the same syntax as the console

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm new to Mongo and I'm really liking playing around with the JavaScript console. Now that I know the basics of Mongo, how can I link the client side javascript with Mongo?

Ideally, I want to use the same syntax the Mongo console offers, now that I got used to it.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133246/access-mongodb-directly-via-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are familiar with node.js, this might be close to what you want:

https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian

"Mongolian DeadBeef is an awesome Mongo DB node.js driver that attempts to closely approximate the mongodb shell."