# Querying mongodb in js and setting result to a variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I was wondering if this is even possible.

What I'm trying to do is something like var user = mycollection.findOne({username : username}) but unfortunately all I get is undefined back.

I'd like to be able to do something like this after:

```
if (pass !== user.password) {
  cb('Password invalid');
}
```

Or is this just an entirely incorrect way to do the comparison? Please halp :(.

Comment: Your question has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133246/access-mongodb-directly-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's an entirely incorrect way to do this. :)

You need to use callbacks with asynchronous operations like this in node.js:

```
mycollection.findOne({username : username}, function(err, user) {
    if (user === null) {
        return cb('Username invalid');
    }
    if (pass !== user.password) {
        return cb('Password invalid');
    }
});
```